# Making a delay between messages

Tags: discord, bots

I am really confused on how to make a delay between messages. I want to make the bot send a message, then wait like 10 seconds, then send a message again.
**For example; making a delay between the startSuccessfulEmbed and the other embed.**

````
var startSuccessfulEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
            .setColor(embedColor)
            .setTitle('Game sucessfully started!!!')
            .addField('Started by', message.author.tag)
        message.channel.send(startSuccessfulEmbed); 
        
        
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Game started')
        .addField('Started by', message.author.username, true)
        .addField('Current Channel', message.channel.name, true)
        .setColor(0x0076EF)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
        .setFooter('STILL CODING');
        message.channel.send(embed);

      }
      
});```
````

Comment: did you try setTimeout?
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Yeah, I tried but it says alert is undefined. ```setTimeout(function(){alert(MessageEmbed); }, 3000);``` @MaximeAshurov

Comment: try call message.channel.send(embed) in setTimeout instead of alert, i'm pretty sure alert will not work in any place of code

Comment: also you should be noticed that 'alert is undefined.' is shown after 3 seconds =)

Comment: I get this when I run setTimeout.

``internal/validators.js:218
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(callback);
    ^``

Comment: show code please)

Comment: ```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Game started')
        .addField('Started by', message.author.username, true)
        .addField('Current Channel', message.channel.name, true)
        .setColor(0x0076EF)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
        .setFooter('STILL CODING');
        message.channel.send(embed);
        setTimeout(3000);

      }
      
});
```

Comment: There @MaximeAshurov

Comment: ohhhh

replace message.channel.send(embed) in your origin code with
setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send(embed) }, 3000)

Comment: setTimeout(3000)
ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK
so 3000 is not valid callback =)

Comment: Thanks! I will respond with the results

Comment: Tysm!!!! It works now!

Comment: checkout my answer with extra stuff if you have more than 2 messages to send =)

Comment: :) I wish I had more rep points so I could like it.

Comment: you can accept it)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`message.channel.send(embed)`

with

`setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send(embed)}, 3000)`

If you have a lot of messages to send, try this

```js
// put this function somewhere in beginning of your file
function intervalBetween(funcs, interval) {
  if (funcs.length == 0) return;
  funcs[0]()
  var index = 1
  var runNext = function() {
    if (index >= funcs.length) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
      funcs[index]()
      index++
      runNext()
    }, interval)
  }
  runNext()
}

// and this
function send(embeds) {
  return embeds.map(function(embed) {
    return function() {
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
  })
}


// ...
// here you create your messages (embed1, embed2...)

var embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
  .setColor(embedColor)
  .setTitle('Game sucessfully started!!!')
  .addField('Started by', message.author.tag)

var embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Game started')
  .addField('Started by', message.author.username, true)
  .addField('Current Channel', message.channel.name, true)
  .setColor(0x0076EF)
  .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
  .setFooter('STILL CODING');


// here you schedule message sending
intervalBetween(send([embed1,embed2]), 1000)
```

checkout [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cLustx1p/)

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped!